# Find documents that match whole query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I want to write query in ElasticSearch that provides results which contains all the words in search query but not only as complete word , but also as subword. For example, if I have Document with this values:

```
{
"first_name":"didier",
"last_name":"drogba"
}
```

and i search for "didi  dro", this document should be returned. if i search for "david drogba", document should be ignored because it doesn't contain word "david" even as subword.
I tried it using ngram tokenizer but couldn't achive what i want.

Index i created

```
PUT doctors
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then added mapping

```
put doctors/_doc/_mapping 
{
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
    }
  }
}
```

add some document

```
post doctors/_doc/1
{
  "first_name": "dito",
  "last_name": "janelidze",
  "specialism": "oftalmologist",
  "location_name":"evex saburtalo clinic",
  "brand": "Evex",
  "address":"kavtaradze street N21"
}
```

and my search query looks like this

```
get doctors/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query": "david jane",
        "fields": ["first_name", "last_name"]
    }
  }
}
```

it gives me document which i inserted but i dont need it because it doesn't contain word "david"

Comment: Could you share the query you've tried. This is possible using Ngram Tokenizer. All that is required is a `bool must` query with two `match` clauses (one on each of first_name and last_name).

Comment: I have updated my question, added some commands from kibana, i hope you understand what ai exactly want to achieve

Comment: For your multimatch query add parameter `"operator": "and"`

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the operator "and" for each words.Use this, work for me (could be use for autocomplete too).

```
settings:
    analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "name_ngrams": {
              "max_gram": "20",
              "type": "edgeNGram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "side": "front"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "partial_name": {
              "type": "custom",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "name_ngrams",
                "standard",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "full_name": {
              "type": "custom",
              "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }


mapping:

    "first_name": {

        "type": "text",
        "index_analyzer": "partial_name",
        "search_analyzer": "full_name"

    },
    "last_name": {

        "type": "text",
        "index_analyzer": "partial_name",
        "search_analyzer": "full_name"

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

### Point 1: Mapping Change

[**N**-Gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) would construct words of specified *length* from input words. This ***length*** is specified as the `min_gram` and `max_gram` in the mapping which if you don't specify would defaults to `1` and `2` respectively.

I've update the mapping you've provided with `min_gram:3` and `max_gram:5` respectively.

The [N-Gram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) would then create the tokens, say for e.g. for `didier` they would be `did, idi, die, ier, didi, idie, dier, didie, idier`, which are eventually stored in inverted index.

With default 1 and 2 as `min_gram` and `max_gram` respectively, notice that `didier` and `david` would have `id` as common sub word, that's why they are returned.

---

Mapping

```
PUT doctors
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 6,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Point 2: Query Change

That said, despite making the mapping change, if your query string has `david jane` using what you have, it would search for `david or jane` in `first_name` OR `last_name`. That means that document `dito janelidze` would still be returned (but will have lower score than one having `david jane`)

Using operator `AND` would make the search as `david AND jane` in `first_name` OR in `last_name` which isn't what you are looking for.

Instead what you can do is make use of below bool query *or* create another field called `name`, copy the values of `first_name` and `last_name` to it using [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) field and use that field to search.

---

Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "first_name": "david"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "last_name": "jane"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately you would need to delete, recreate the index and ingest the documents again as the changes required are at mapping level.

Hope this helps!